# Send a constructor as a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of the nice things in Javascript is the ability to send functions as parameters. I have an application where I have to send classes as parameters.

As a simple example, I need a function that makes some tests on a class, and I want to send the class as a parameter:

```
test(ClassA);
test(ClassB);
```

where ClassA and ClassB are two different classes.

A 1st possible solution is:

```
function test(theClass) {
    var object1 = new theClass();
    var object2 = new theClass();
    assert(object1.toString()===object2.toString());
    // ... more asserts ...
}
```

This works well but it doesn't allow me to send parameters for constructing the classes. For example, ClassA may have several iniialization options, and I may want to test each option separately.

A 2nd possible solution is:

```
function test(theClass, theInitializationOptions) {
    var object1 = new theClass(theInitializationOptions);
    var object2 = new theClass(theInitializationOptions);
    assert(object1.toString()===object2.toString());
    // ... more asserts ...
}
```

Which I can use like this:

```
test(ClassA, {option1: 1, option2: 2...});
test(ClassA, {option1: 2, option2: 3...});
test(ClassB, {});
```

This works well, but it is cumbersome - it requires me to send two parameters, and if the function "test" uses sub-functions, it will have to send these two parameters all the way down. I am looking for a function 'test' that takes only one parameter.

A 3rd possible solution is to send an initialization function instead of a class:

```
function test(theClassConstructor) {
    var object1 = theClassConstructor();
    var object2 = theClassConstructor();
    assert(object1.toString()==object2.toString());
}
```

Which I can use like this:

```
test(function() { return new ClassA(1,2,3); })   /* test class A */
test(function() { return new ClassB(4,5); })     /* test class B */
```

The problem is that this 'test' function takes a function instead of a class.

I am looking for a function 'test' that will take a class as an argument (i.e. it will initialize a new object with the "new" operator), but still allow the caller to pass arguments together with the class.

In other words, I am looking for a way to bind arguments with a constructor.

Is this possible in Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Function#bind to do this,

```
test(MyClass.bind(this, 1, 2, 3));

function test(klass) {
    var c = new klass();
    /* stuff */
}
```

The first parameter `this` is ignored when using the `new` keyword.